# .obj files triangle_fan or triangles

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, mesh

I am using Blender to create .obj files and then trying to write a custom parser to read in the file and create a mesh. I have a few questions. My example is using a cube from blender, but I want to expand my questions beyond the cube.

When I create a cube in blender and save it as a .obj file I get this...

```
# Blender v2.63 (sub 0) OBJ File: ''
# www.blender.org
mtllib cube.mtl
o Cube_Cube.001
v -0.911915 -0.851241 1.196067
v -0.911915 -0.851241 -0.803933
v 1.088085 -0.851241 -0.803933
v 1.088085 -0.851241 1.196067
v -0.911915 1.148759 1.196067
v -0.911915 1.148759 -0.803933
v 1.088085 1.148759 -0.803933
v 1.088085 1.148759 1.196067
usemtl 
s off
f 2 1 5 6
f 6 7 3 2
f 7 8 4 3
f 1 4 8 5
f 1 2 3 4
f 8 7 6 5
```

And my Mesh rendering method looks like this....

```
@Override
    public void draw(GL10 gl)
    {
        super.draw(gl);
        gl.glColor4f(255, 0, 255, 150);
        gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3,GL10.GL_FLOAT,0,vertexBuffer);

        gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN,vertexBuffer.array().length,GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,indexBuffer);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
        gl.glColor4f(255, 255, 255, 255);
    }
```

How do I populate my index buffer and vertex buffer to be able to draw this cube. Can I have all the vertices in one "drawElements" function or do I have to do it triangle by triangle? Will the .obj file ever make more than four vertices a face? (like a 2D Pentagon or Hexagon?) If so, how would I draw those? Do .OBJ files use Triang fans or strips?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In terms of actually efficiency boost, there most likely isn't one if you store the buffers on the GPU. If you are calculating the data on the CPU and buffering it to the GPU every frame (which you should avoid if you can and just store it on the GPU itself) then you are reducing the buffer size by using triangle fans/strips. However, during the rasterization process, unless the rasterizer loop has the ability to iterate through complex shapes with greater than 3 verteces (which I HIGHLY DOUBT) it will have to triangulate the polygons anyway.

I'm not a heavy android programmer but if the version of OpenGL you are using has "GenerateBuffer()" & "DrawArrays()", USE THEM. Since using triangle fans/strips only really help with the buffering speed between hardware components, there is probably no optimization to be done if your android device does not have a dedicated graphics device.

In terms of how you would do it, you just de-triangulate a list of triangles. With triangle strips, you would have to iterate through all triangles and find a list of them with the same 2 vertex position as each previous vertex. For triangle fans, you would need to iterate through all triangles, and find a list of them with the same 2 vertex position as each previous vertex, AND they all must have an identical origin vertex of rotation.

The above description is just the inverse of the triangulation algorithms:

  Triangle Strip (given a list of "n" verteces):
      each triangle is "new Triangle(n-2, n-1, n)" where (n > 2)
  Triangle Fan (given a list of "n" verteces):
      each triangle is "new Triangle(0, n-1, n)" where "0" is the first element and (n > 2)

For quadrilaterals (as with your example code) you can use the triangular fan approach above (triangle strip does not work from blender obj file quads).

Comment: Thanks for the description of triangle strip *and* triangle fan. I kept conflating them as the same thing in my head.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL and graphic cards are simply machines, which draw triangles really fast. Therefore you should focus on triangles first. Ignore quads. Quads are typically replaced by a set of two triangles anyway and you have no control how are they divided. Pentagons and more give even more problems. Ignore strips and fans too. A generic 3d model is usually triangle only anyway. Fans and strips can be used as an optimization in special cases. For example a triangle strip is really useful if you model a landscape in the form of a grid from a height-map.

Comment: Makes sense.... How then do I interpret the index buffer given to me in the .obj file? They list the faces as a set of 4 indices rather than 6. (6 being the two triangles that make up the face)

Comment: f 2 1 5 6 - you can interpret this as two triangles (2,1,5) and (1,5,6). Not sure if the ordering is correct. Then load these two triangles into your buffer. The obj format can have any number of vertices as long as they create a convex polygon. It is up to you how you will load that. You might use a triangle fan in this case, but then you will have a lot of OpenGL api calls (switching from fans to triangles etc). It is faster to have one big triangle buffer and render that in one api call.